# NSURLConnection doesn't start

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am writing location based app, get weather information through API by using NSURLConnection for current/other places .At first time I sent request its working successfully. But next time I want to refer the information for same place it not working while NSURLConnection is not call the any delegate methods.

this is my code:

```
NSString *strs=[@"http://www.earthtools.org/timezone-1.1/" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",place.latitude,place.longitude]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strs]];

self.reqTimeZone=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[self.reqTimeZone start];
```

Comment: Does this block of code execute on main thread or background thread ? If you are running on background thread you need to attach connection to thread's runloop.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you mean `NSURLConnection` (`NSConnection` doesn't exist). `NSURLConnection` can only be used once. See [Reusing an instance of NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188420/reusing-an-instance-of-nsurlconnection).

Another gotcha with `NSURLConnection` is that it must be ran on a thread with a runloop. The main thread automatically has a run loop, but methods called on GCD and `NSOperation` threads need to have the runloop created explicitly. In practice you probably don't need to run `NSURLConnection` on a background thread. The download operation will not block the main thread. If you do decide to run `NSURLConnection` on a run loop the easiest way to do it is probably to create an `NSOperation` subclass and create the run loop inside of `-main`.

Comment: i sent NSURLConnection request it is working fine.now i want to refresh the information i.e resend the NSURLConnection.Refresh is working when call from IBAction of button.But is not working from NSThread method. how to i solve this problem.Thank for replay