# Best way to write a CalDAV client library in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, caldav

I am needing to write a CalDAV client library for the Mac, and I just wanted to make sure on what would be the best way to write it.

I am wondering if I should just use NSURLRequest or should I go to the socket level, or something in between?

My concern about using just NSURLRequest is that a new connection would be made for each call, instead of having 1 open connection that all "requests" go through.

Am I missing something?

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSURLRequest` doesn't actually create any connections.  It just encapsulates the parameters of the request.  `NSURLConnection` actually creates the connection to the server and sends the request.  Under the covers, `NSURLConnection` instances share and reuse TCP connections, according to this answer:

[NSURLConnection is run many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886810/nsurlconnection-is-run-many-times/888101#888101)

So you should just use `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection` if their APIs suit you.

#### UPDATE

Since `NSURLConnection` has been deprecated since iOS 9 / macOS 10.11, you should use `NSURLSession`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSURLRequest`. Despite the naming, an `NSURLConnection` object does not have a one-to-one correspondence with a TCP connection. In fact, `NSURLConnection` might be more appropriately named `NSURLRequestLoadingManager` or something—it's just an object that tracks the progress of that particular request.

The underlying TCP connections are managed by Cocoa, and you don't need to worry about their lifecycle.