# iOS : Keep Http connection Open

Tags: iphone, ios

I had been using `CFHttp` and `NSUrlConnection`. These classes create a new connection every time to do a http send and receive.

Basically i need a single connection to perform all my send and receive.

Open connection -> send http request -> receive http response ->send http request -> receive http response-> Close connection.

Is there any way to do this.

Comment: Try using zeromq library. You'd need to implement other side of the connection in zeromq too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSUrlConnection will automagically keep open and re-use a connection for you, via the HTTP 1.1 protocol. (See this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/888101/348476)). It should do this out of the box, unless you're doing something to modify its default behaviour.

I recommend using a network sniffer to verify that connection re-use is happening (or not), and to  verify after what amount of time the connection might be dropped (and hence re-opened on next request). [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is a superb network analyzer with good protocol support.

You could also use a third party library; [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is nice, well designed, and gets good press. (I used to use ASIHttpRequest but it's recently been retired from active development, and its code structure is more monolithic.)

Comment: using iOS 9.3 , im not able to use http keep alive it seems. Please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38773688/ios-doesnt-to-use-http-keep-alive-very-high-latency