# Reusing an https connection on iOS

Tags: ios, https

I've written a short iOS application that contacts a server via the usual:

```
NSString *URLString = @"http://mysite/script.php?foo=1";
NSURL *getURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
NSURLRequest *getRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:getURL];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:getRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

This works OK, but as I access the web site relatively frequently with various values of `foo`, and as we plan to migrate to `https`, people have raised the question about the overhead on the phone of setting up and tearing down the `NSURLConnection` every time. I see [this answer saying that the class handles caching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/888101/1270789), but is that true for `https` too?

Comment: I sure like using afhttpclient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my tests, yes, it does appear to be true that the NSURLConnection class does caching of https to some extent. I did like the look of [AFHTTPClient](http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html) as mentioned in the comment, but due to various issues I was unable to use it in this project, however.